# Программа завершается нулевым кодом при операторе "&&" и отображает два значения при операторе "||", вместо одного

Tags: c#

Условие задачи:
Для данного `x` вычислить значение следующей функции `f`, принимающей значения целого типа: `0`, если `x < 0`, `f(x 1, если x принадлежит [0,1), )= [2,3), ... , –1 если x принадлежит [1,2), , [3,4), ...` .

Код:

```
string f = Console.ReadLine();
double x = Convert.ToDouble(f);
if (x < 0)
    Console.Write("Значение F= 0");
if ((x >= 0) && (x < 1) && (x <= 2) && (x < 3))
    Console.Write("Значение F = 1");
if ((x >= 1) && (x < 2) && (x >= 3) && (x < 4))
    Console.Write("Значение F = -1");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Так же пробовал ставить вместо оператора `&&` оператор `||`, в нули уже не откидывало, но выводило сразу два значения. Прошу помочь и объяснить в чём проблема с кодом.

Comment: Отредактируйте в вопросе когда чему равна функция. Но проблема у вас в том, что вам нужно совместить и && и ||, на примере второго: `(x >= 0) && (x < 1) || (x <= 2) && (x < 3)`, а лучше так: `(0 <= x) && (x < 1) || (2 <= x) && (x < 3)` (чтобы было похоже на двойное неравенство `0 <= x < 1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string f = Console.ReadLine();
        double x = Convert.ToDouble(f);
        if (x < 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Значение F= 0");
        else  if (((x >= 0) && (x < 1)) || ((x >= 2) && (x < 3)))
            Console.WriteLine("Значение F = 1");
        else if (((x >= 1) && (x < 2)) || ((x >= 3) && (x < 4)))
            Console.WriteLine("Значение F = -1");
        Console.ReadKey();
```